# QPython3 problems with Javascript in HTML GUI

Tags: javascript, android, qpython3

QPython3, Android 6.0; I guess JS cann't instance var droid = new Android();
Any hints to solve the problem?

Python Code (the same in both cases!):

```
import android

droid=android.Android()

droid.webViewShow('file:///storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts3/test10_le_HTMLGUI_01.html')

while True:
    result=droid.eventWaitFor('sag').result
    droid.ttsSpeak(result['data'])
```

HTML-Code: test10_le_HTMLGUI_01.html (Case 1):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Text To Speech</title>
    <script>
      var n = prompt("Hello JavaScript","");
      var droid = new Android();
      var speak = function() { 
        var n = prompt("Hello JavaScript","");
        droid.eventPost("sag", document.getElementById("sag").value, 1);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form onsubmit="speak(); return false;">
      <label for="sag">What is your message?</label>
      <input type="text" id="sag" />
      <input type="submit" value="Speak" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

HTML-Code (Case 2):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Text To Speech</title>
    <script>
      var droid = new Android();
      var n = prompt("Hello JavaScript","");
      var speak = function() { 
        var n = prompt("Hello JavaScript","");
        droid.eventPost("sag", document.getElementById("sag").value, 1);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form onsubmit="speak(); return false;">
      <label for="sag">What is your message?</label>
      <input type="text" id="sag" />
      <input type="submit" value="Speak" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

While in case 1 the prompt("Hello JavaScript",""); is executed it is not in case 2!

QPython3 (Android 6) SL4A eventPost() and eventWaitFor() works fine on the following example (for add. info refer to  http://www.mithril.com.au/android/doc/):

```
import android, time
droid=android.Android()
t = 'Geschafft!'
print('debug 1')
droid.eventPost('Event1', t, 1)
print('debug 2')
print('debug 3')
result=droid.eventWaitFor('Event1').result
droid.ttsSpeak(result['data'])
print('debug 4')
print(result['data'])
```

Proof: If you comment out the line droid.eventPost('Event1', t, 1) then eventWaitFor() will block forever!

Maybe we 've a similar Problem in [QPython3 webViewShow - Script doesn't receiving data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253083/qpython3-webviewshow-script-doesnt-receiving-data/42912464#42912464) 
and in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478310/qpython-webview-javascript-android-object

Regards
Gustav (2017-03-21)

Answer (score 1):

Use bottle() instead of JavaScript. It's already integrated in QPython3 and provides solutions for pretty the same tasks.
Find a tutorial for bottle() at
https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/bottle-docs.pdf

Regards
Gustav

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same problem. As far as I found, at least in recent version you're required to add an Android interface when using webview by calling JavascriptAddInterface, and from the SL4A sources seems like it doesn't.
Too bad...